# Fastest way to convert dtypes for big datasets in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

So, I'm working with a relatively big dataset and I feel like it's taking to much time to convert the columns into their proper dtypes.

So far, I'm using `apply` with `to_datetime` and `to_numeric` like so:

```
df.iloc[:,[0,1,9]] = df.iloc[:,[0,1,9]].apply(pd.to_datetime, 
errors='coerce')
df.iloc[:,2:8] = df.iloc[:,2:8].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

I was able to convert the columns, but it took ~20 minutes. There must be a quicker way?

If not, are my only choices to cut down the dataset for data exploration or get a faster computer?

EDIT: The problem was mainly due to using to_datetime without formatting the date and time. There was also improvement in performance when I removed iloc and apply, though it is not as significant as formatting the date and time.

Here's the time each scenario took:

- No formatting using iloc took 1027.11 s to run
- No formatting without using iloc took 789.15 s to run
- datetime with formatting took 19.47 s to run

Huge improvement. This was on a dataset with 2,049,280 rows. Thanks @ScottBoston and @DiegoAgher!

Comment: How was this dataset created in the first place? If it was read from a file it'd better to pass hints for the dtypes.

Comment: I used pd.read_csv('dataset.txt', sep=';', low_memory=False). I tried using dtypes, but I kept getting an error telling me that I couldn't convert the columns into floats.

Comment: See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034689/why-is-pandas-to-datetime-slow-for-non-standard-time-format-such-as-2014-12-31

Comment: I used dtypes = {'Date': 'str', 'Everything_else': 'float64'} and then inserted dtypes=dtypes inside read_csv.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks, Scott. I just realized that it is definitely to_datetime which is causing the problem. to_numeric took 5 seconds on its own. I will add the format string to to_datetime and see if it helps.

Comment: @JacquesThibodeau Please post back the results.  I am curious

Comment: @ScottBoston It worked! It took ~20 seconds. I'm gonna run it without formatting to see the actual time difference.

Comment: @JacquesThibodeau Awesome.  What sort of time difference did you get on how many rows?

Comment: @ScottBoston I just edited the OP a second ago with the answer to your question, have a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apply` function usually takes quite some execution time.
Column based operations are faster, you could do:

```
df['column0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column0'], errors='coerce')
```

and so on for the rest of the columns.

Also, if you have a specific format for the column you could try specifying it to speed things up.

```
df['column0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column0'], format=format, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: The OP is iterating over the cols of interest so what they're  trying already takes this into account

Comment: I think I read a while back on Stack Overflow someone mentioned that adding formatting to time will help with speed.  Explicitly add time format string to the to_datetime.

Comment: @EdChum I just wanted to take away the `.iloc[:, ...]` operation since I thought this could be adding up execution time.

Comment: @ScottBoston updated the answer with your contribution, which I think is also very relevant ;)

Comment: @DiegoAgher In this case it's not a big deal since I only have 10 columns, but I want to add iloc in case I use a dataset with much more columns so I didn't have to write a new line for each column... haha