# pandas to_datetime is so slow for big datas, how to improve it or just find a way to replace

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a Series in DataFrame from string to datetime, and i use the method pandas.to_datetime, it's worked!  BUT it is very slow. 
the strings is formated as time, like '2017-1-1 00:00:00'. it's a big data, more than 3000000 data。
Are there some ways to make it work faster?
appreciate your help！

Comment: Can u add the example string datetime from your dataset?

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32034914?

Comment: thanks! John, it's helped a lot~