# Pandas to Datetime conversion running slow/not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have a decently large data set nothing crazy, but when I run below code to convert to date time, any reason why the cells seems to run for a very long amount of time? Any way I can improve code for performance?

Code:

```
df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

where the timstamp column value originally looks like below

```
Wed Nov 22 08:31:24 +0000 2017
```

Thanks

Comment: which version of pandas are you using? with version 1.1.2, I cannot reproduce this, at least with artificial data. the conversion is pretty fast, no matter how I convert to datetime (auto-detect of the format or setting a specific format).

Comment: Hi I have version '1.1.2'

Comment: ok did you benchmark the individual steps, I mean parsing to datetime and from there to string? it seems to me that the conversion back to string is taking some time... using `.astype(str)` or `.apply(pd.Timestamp.isoformat)` might be faster than strftime.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, so Panda's `to_datetime` method is notoriously slow if you don't explicitly specify the format. Here is the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for the method, and here is the [standard](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for how the format should be set up.

I don't know how exactly your time data is set up, but this should set you on the right path:

```
import pandas as pd


# Weekday as abbreviated name "%a"
df = pd.DataFrame(["Wed"], columns = ["timestamp"])
df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], format="%a")
print(df)

# Month as abbreviated "%b"
df = pd.DataFrame(["Wed Nov"], columns = ["timestamp"])
df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], format="%a %b")
print(df)

# Day with zero-padded decimal "%d"
df = pd.DataFrame(["Wed Nov 22"], columns = ["timestamp"])
df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], format="%a %b %d")
print(df)

# Time as hour:minute:second "%H:%M:%S"
df = pd.DataFrame(["Wed Nov 22 08:31:24"], columns = ["timestamp"])
df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S")
print(df)

# UTC offset (%z)
df = pd.DataFrame(["Wed Nov 22 08:31:24 +0000"], columns = ["timestamp"])
df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z") 
print(df)

# Year is "%Y"
df = pd.DataFrame(["Wed Nov 22 08:31:24 +0000 2017"], columns = ["timestamp"])
df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
print(df)
```

Comment: alright ;-) still - I cannot reproduce the OP's issue. With the same pandas version 1.1.2 on Python 3.8.5 x64, it makes almost no difference performance-wise if I specify a format or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46043826/798335) with a several possible solutions

[The reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32034914/798335):

> This is because pandas falls back to dateutil.parser.parse for parsing the strings when it has a non-default format or when no format string is supplied (this is much more flexible, but also slower).

Fix for your issue with best performance

```py
def format_datetime(dt_series):

    def get_split_date(strdt):
        split_date = strdt.split()
        str_date = split_date[1] + ' ' + split_date[2] + ' ' + split_date[5] + ' ' + split_date[3]
        return str_date

    dt_series = pd.to_datetime(dt_series.apply(lambda x: get_split_date(x)), format = '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')

    return dt_series


df["created_at"] = format_datetime(df["timestamp"])
```

**Benchmarks**

```py
timestamps = [
    'Wed Nov 22 08:31:24 +0000 2017', 'Wed Nov 22 08:33:24 +0000 2018', 'Wed Nov 22 08:31:24 +0000 2019'
]
df = pd.DataFrame(timestamps * 300000, columns=['timestamp'])
```

```py
%timeit df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

> 4min 8s ± 1min 10s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```py
%timeit df["created_at1"] = format_datetime(df["timestamp"])
```

> 5.6 s ± 1.18 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)